# Can I check whether my webcam's LED is software or hardware controlled?

Tags: usb, security, webcam

We all have heard of malware that is able to take control of a webcam and spy on the person sitting in front of it. Some of those are even coded well enough to activate the webcam without lighting the LED that indicates recording. This only works of course if the LED is controllable by software and not hard-wired to light up if the cam is on.

Is it somehow possible to check which is the case? Can I be sure my webcam is off if its LED is off? Or not?

Currently running Ubuntu 16.04, kernel 4.4.0-38-generic, output of `lsusb -v` regarding my webcam device can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/A1m13vC5).

Comment: We have all heard of Windows malware that ....

Comment: @waltinator I never used the word "Windows" in my question. Unrelated of whether there is malware which does it or not and for what systems, is it possible to find out whether this webcam can be accessed without its LED lighting up?

Comment: Do you have a Linux/Unix example of such malware? Or is this "'Fear of Ghosts"?

Comment: Very interesting question I suppose. Especially due to recent news about cia malware that can hack Linux computers too. I think it is a good idea to start a bounty

Answer (score 3):

Short of writing an exploit, you can contact the webcam manufacturer. Past that, you might be able to open your camera up, and take a look, but this can always be problematic.

In *most* cases on modern webcams, [the camera light is controlled by the webcam's onboard firmware](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/can-webcams-be-turned-on-without-the-indicator-light). Without having access to the firmware, this makes our life somewhat difficult, as you'd have to extract it from the chip or try to get a compiled image.

However, there's still a concern - even webcams with hardware controlled lights may still be manipulated into turning on without enabling the light (or without you noticing the light). Software like Metasploit have [special functions](https://kb.help.rapid7.com/discuss/59b82deb3eaea6001ae3da44) that turn the webcam on, take a photo, and immediately turn it off. Depending on your camera's  hardware, this could happen too fast for the light to register - this was a known issue on MacBook Pros once upon a time.

If you're truly paranoid about your webcam being used against you, it's best to either unplug it (instead of disabling it through software) or use some privacy guard device.

Comment: My _"privacy guard device"_ is duct tape.